# Can one use a MySQL backend for user authentication in a strongswan VPN server?

Tags: mysql, vpn, strongswan

We have installed and configured a `strongswan` VPN server with username / password authentication. Is it possible to store the users' credentials in a `MySQL` backend and configure strongswan to use the backend for this purpose?

So far I just found a mysql plugin for configuration purposes and Xauth backends using AAA, radius, etc. . Unfortunately this is not what we need.

Answer (score 2):

The [sql plugin](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/SQL) provides configuration details but also credentials stored in a database.  It's not required to store everything in the database and the data can be combined with that provided by other plugins.  So it is possible to use the *stroke* plugin to provide configurations from `ipsec.conf` and certificates from `/etc/ipsec.d/` but define the username and passwords used for EAP/XAuth authentication in a database instead of in `ipsec.secrets`.  The driver provided by the *mysql* plugin is required by the *sql* plugin to access MySQL databases.

As mentioned above, you are free to ignore the tables that provide configurations and instead just define the secrets and usernames in the `shared_secrets` and `identities` tables, respectively, and associated them via the `shared_secret_identity` table. The `id2sql` script (not installed but built in the `scripts` folder in the strongSwan build directory) provides an easy way to generate entries for the `identities` table.

Here is some example SQL data (more information regarding the types can be found [here](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/SQLite)):

```
INSERT INTO identities (
  type, data
) VALUES ( /* type=ID_RFC822_ADDR, data=carol@strongswan.org */
  3, X'6361726f6c407374726f6e677377616e2e6f7267'
);

INSERT INTO shared_secrets (
  type, data
) VALUES ( /* type=SHARED_EAP/XAUTH, data=Ar3etTnp01qlpOgb */
  2, X'4172336574546e703031716c704f6762'
);

/* assumes the entries above are the first ones in their respective
 * tables, as their id column is auto_increment */
INSERT INTO shared_secret_identity (
  shared_secret, identity
) VALUES (
  1, 1 
);
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone that stumbles upon this, I used this excellent guide: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mas90/resources/strongswan to do the basic setup and then the setup the database entries as above.

Afterwards, I use free letsencrypt certificates and the `CN="myvpnserver.mydomain.com"` so I set `leftcert=myvpnserver.mydomain.com` in my `ipsec.conf`. I then added an entry into the mysql table identities with type '2' and data `'myvpnserver.mydomain.com'` (have to use id2sql script from strongswan to convert the data entry). Then I got the automatically assigned id number for that entry from the my identities database and the shared secret id like the previous entry in order to make an entry into shared_secret_identity like this:

```
INSERT INTO shared_secret_identity (shared_secret, identity) VALUES ( id_of_user_logging_in_that_was_set_in_shared_secrets_database, automatically_assigned_id_number_for_myvpnser.mydomain.com_in_identities_database );
```

After that it worked.