# Can one use a MySQL backend for user authentication in a strongswan VPN server (new)?

Tags: mysql, ipsec, strongswan

We have installed and configured a strongswan VPN server with username / password authentication. Is it possible to store the users' credentials in a MySQL backend and configure strongswan to use the backend for this purpose?

this is [old question](https://serverfault.com/questions/716552/can-one-use-a-mysql-backend-for-user-authentication-in-a-strongswan-vpn-server?rq=1) but ,
I don't know what settings to add in the database ?

---

update3 :solved, thank you;

Comment: You need to provide a lot more details (e.g. complete server logs, or a dump of the actual database).

Comment: You might have to associate the secret with the server identity too (type 9, the encoding can be generated with the `id2sql` script or `pki --dn`). You can see the queries at the end of the MySQL log.

Comment: thank you very very much , solved.